# Determine function even or odd. Why?

Tags: functions

I've been asked to determine whether a function is even or odd. 
Why is this useful?

Comment: To let you learn how to identify odd and even functions.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Some_facts) are some properties of even and odd functions.

Comment: Symmetry is our friend, it is often useful in solving problems. Evenness, oddness are frequently occurring types of symmetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx = \begin{cases}
&0,& \; \text{if $f(x)$ is odd}\\
& 2 \int_0^a f(x) \, dx ,& \; \text{if $f(x)$ is even}\end{cases}$

Comment: And that's just *one* of the reasons why it's useful.

Comment: Of course you are right. It's just to show that the concept is useful :).

Comment: I know but I wanted to emphasise that there are more reasons, just in case the OP might think "ok... so what?"